# Позиционирование flexbox в css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
section {
  width: 900px;
  height: 200px;
}

.services_imgs {
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 79px;
}

.services_i:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(img/icon1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.services_i:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(img/icon2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.services_i:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(img/icon3.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.services_i {
  display: block;
  height: 73px;
  width: 74px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <section>

      <div class="services_imgs">
        <div class="services_i">

        </div>
        <div class="services_i">

        </div>
        <div class="services_i">

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Вопрос: можно ли выровнить services_imgs по центру section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно:

```
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 900px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.services_imgs {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 1px solid brown;
}

.services_i:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

.services_i:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.services_i:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.services_i {
  display: block;
  height: 73px;
  width: 74px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <div class="services_imgs">
    <div class="services_i">

    </div>
    <div class="services_i">

    </div>
    <div class="services_i">

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```